# Actionbar menu onclick

Tags: android, onclick, actionbarsherlock

Is there any way to use the standard menu button in the action bar to do something? In my case a sliding menu, I already have code that works in the `onClick` of a normal button. I just want to use the menu button in the action bar instead. Is this possible? Or will I have to customize the action bar and not use the button that is already there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean the ActionBar Home icon.

**First you have to enable it**

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

**Then you have to handle the event**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //do your work
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

FYI if you want to follow the Navigation drawer pattern you should read this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Comment: Thank you, it seems that I was just missing `android.R.id.home:`